# asp:RequiredFieldValidator no me funciona con ajaxtoolkit:ModalPopupExtender

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net

Me explico, estoy combinando estos dos controles en ASP.net, la idea es que no sea visible el PopUp hasta que se llenen varios TextBox, el problema es que no me esta respetando esta validación y me muestra el PopUp independientemente que el campo este vació, a continuación anexo el código:

```
div class="panel-body">
            Name:
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" ValidationGroup="e"/>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator_txtMiles" ControlToValidate="txtName" EnableClientScript="true" 
            Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="true" Text="Miles is a required field" Enabled="true" runat="server" ValidationGroup="e">
            </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <br />

            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="btnDisplayName" runat="server" Text="Display Name" CausesValidation="false"
                OnClientClick="return DisplayName()" ValidationGroup="e"/>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDummy" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
            <ajaxtoolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" BehaviorID="mpe" runat="server"
                PopupControlID="pnlPopup" TargetControlID="lnkDummy" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
            </ajaxtoolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlPopup" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" Style="display: none">
                <div class="header">
                    Modal Popup
                </div>
                <div class="body">
                Your name: <span id="lblName"></span>
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="Close" OnClientClick="return HideModalPopup()" />
            </div>
            </asp:Panel>
        </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
        function DisplayName() {
            console.log(Page_ClientValidate());
            if (Page_ClientValidate()) {
                $get("lblName").innerHTML = $get("<%=txtName.ClientID %>").value;
                $find("mpe").show();
            }
            return false;
        }
        function HideModalPopup() {
            $find("mpe").hide();
            return false;
        }
    </script>
```